# Prove that $B_{0}=\{x\in (0, 1) \mid x=m/2^{n} \;\text{for some} \; m\in\mathbb{N} \;\text{and}\; n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis

Haven't got any clue yet, should we prove there is a bijection between $B_0$ and $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Do you know that $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is countable?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, yes, I guess I know there is a bijection $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, but would you please enlighten me about how it is related to this problem?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I see it now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another attempt:

Let $B:=${$m/2^n| m,n \in \mathbb{N}$}.

$f: \mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow$ $B$,

$f:(m,n) \mapsto m/2^n.$

$f$ is a surjective map from a countable

set $ \mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}$ to $B$.

Hence $B$ is countable.

$B_0 \subset B$, i.e

$B_0$ as a subset of a countable set $B$ is countable.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most elegant, but you could define a function
$$
\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}\to B_0
$$
via
$$
(m,n)\mapsto\frac{m}{2^n}\mapsto f(m/2^n)
$$
where $f$ is defined case-wise as $f(q)=q$ if $q\in B_0$, and $f(q)=\frac{1}{2}$ if $q\not\in B_0$. The composite $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to B_0$ is surjective, so $B_0$ is countable since $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the map $f: \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \to B_0$ given by: $f(m,n) = \dfrac{m}{2^n}$, and $f$ is a bijection and the latter set is countable since former also is.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: $f$ is not well defined, as one would have $(1,1)=f(1/2)=f(2/4)=(2,2)$... I think it would be best to define $f$ the other way around, i.e. $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Q},(m,n)\mapsto m/2^n$, and notice that the image of this map contains $B_0$, as in the answer of Ben West.